# How to add data to UITableViewController

Tags: swift

I have a problem with some code in my project. I want to set a UITableViewController with a prototype cell with three labels. When i click on the add button appears  an add controller with three text fields to add some data. I want that this data appear in the cell's labels of the UITableViewController but i don't understand how to set code for this. Can you help me?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please give more input.

Comment: Add button inside a cell? where will be the text fields? Which cell it should reflect

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you really don't know much about tableViews. But its ok. Try to use this code for your table view...

```
  import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

        let sampleData:[String] = ["data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5"]



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //table view datasource and delegate
            self.tableview.dataSource = self
            self.tableview.delegate = self
            self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //returns number of rows in table view
           return self.sampleData.count
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

            let label:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel

            label.text = sampleData[indexPath.row]


            return cell


        }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

          //user selected a row
            //print the table view row number

println(indexPath.row)


        }






    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi nachshon fertel,
you can see my file at this link: http://www.justbeamit.com/n53h7